# why C# not allow operator overloading?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

why c# not allowed operator overloading while C++ do?

I got this error, when trying to overload.

**Overloadable binary operator expected**

My sample code looks like,

```
public static MyClass operator +=(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2)
        {
           ...
        }
```

Comment: @User: I edited my answer to explain why your code didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can overload operators in C#:

- [MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(VS.71).aspx)

Before you decide to use operator overloading, please read at the very least, the following:

- [Criticisms of Operator Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Criticisms)

---

**EDIT in response to op's edit:**

The `+=` is a non-overloadable operator. However, it resolves to `+`, and `+` is overloadable. Have a [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(VS.71).aspx) for which operators you can and can not overload.

**Operators that can be overloaded:**

`+`, `-`, `!`, `~`, `++`, `--`, `true`, `false`

`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`

`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` (The comparison operators can be overloaded but see note in link)

Answer (score 7):

Operator overloading, C# allows. (Yoda version)

Answer (score 4):

It does allow operator overloading..

that said, it's generally recommended *not* to override operators since it changes the semantics of your code and therefore makes it less maintainable by others.

Comment: Unless the overloaded operators provide appropriate semantics for the objects they're operating on. The classic example of '+' on a Complex number class is a perfectly acceptable use of operator overloading.

Comment: Plus the casting operators for example in Linq to XML make reading element values very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

c# does allow operator overloading. MSDN tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can overload operators in C#. [Operator Overloading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx)