# How do I override && (logical and operator)?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Everything else seems to follow this pattern, but when I try:

```
public static ColumnOperation operator&&(ColumnOperation lhs, ColumnOperation rhs)
{
    return new ColumnBooleanOperation(lhs, rhs, ExpressionType.And);
}
```

I get "Overloadable binary operator expected". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **How** is it not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: "Overloadable binary operator expected"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354065/why-c-sharp-not-allow-operator-overloading

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You may want to read this. It also provides a good example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: `Everything else seems to follow this patter` who is everyone?

Comment: @asawyer Presumably he means overloading other operators.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I read "everyone" instead of "everything" that makes more sense.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Conditional logic operators cannot be overloaded.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx):

> The conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded, but they are evaluated using **&** and **|**, which can be overloaded.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691312%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) provides more information on how to implement your own custom **&&** and **||** operators.

Answer (score 16):

You can't overload `&&` directly, but you can overload the `false`, `true` and `&` operators - see [operator &&](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-)

```
public static bool operator true(ColumnOperation x)
{
    ...
}

public static bool operator false(ColumnOperation x)
{
    ...
}

public static ColumnOperation operator &(ColumnOperation lhs, ColumnOperation rhs)
{
    return new ColumnBooleanOperation(lhs, rhs, ExpressionType.And);
}
```

This gives the same functionality. Specifically, from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11133-user-defined-conditional-logical-operators):

> The operation `x && y` is evaluated as `T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y)`
> [...]
> `x` is first evaluated and operator `false` is invoked on the result to determine if `x` is definitely false. Then, if `x` is definitely false, the result of the operation is the value previously computed for `x`.

This indicates that short-circuit evaluation will also work as expected when the above overloads are implemented correctly. Overloading the `|` can also be done in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 7):

See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) on which operators can be overloaded:

> The conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded, but they are evaluated using & and |, which can be overloaded.

That refers to the `&&` and `||` operators.

So, in short, override `&` and you'll get `&&` for free along with it.

Answer (score 4):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx):

> &&, || : The conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded, but they are
>   evaluated using & and |, which can be overloaded.

So you can't override that, but you can override `&` or `|`.